# Choosing the Kubernetes PV and Access Mode

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling, persistent-volumes

We use parquet files and have 2 containers; one acts as a writer to the parquet file and another as the reader. Should I choose EFS or EBS as PV, we need both auto-scaling and low-latency

Keeping auto-scaling in mind the many reader pods can spin up and at any time there should be only one writer and there can be multiple readers.

Which Access Modes and PV are better suited for this use case

Comment: Can you share the content using some other path, maybe a non-filesystem storage service with a network API (S3)?  Sharing files in a clustered environment is tricky in general.  An EBS volume can only be attached to one EC2 instance, which in Kubernetes translates to it only supporting `ReadWriteOnce` access mode and only being usable on one Node at a time, which could be a challenging scheduling constraint.

Comment: The library we are using is not compatible with S3. Is there any tool which I can use to keep all EBS in sync. Like I checked Longhorn, seaweedfs, juicefs etc.. but not sure whether they really fit my use case